# brew installed Vim in Terminal with RVM (Ruby 1.9.3), MacVim and Command-T

Tags: vim, terminal, rvm, macvim

I'm using RVM (1.17.7) and Ruby 1.9.3p362. In the long run I want to move over to Vim in the Terminal with Tmux. I'm trying to learn how to install and run with my choices for plugins instead of defaulting to Janus, just trying to learn it all and not be a cargo cult programmer.

I did a brew install of Vim git clone of Command-T (I'm using Pathogen) while the Ruby was set to 1.9.3... and everything is good in Terminal using Vim and Command-T. When I run :ruby puts RUBY_VERSION in Terminal Vim, it gives 1.9.3 back. The Command-T works fine too.

When I try and use the same Command-T in MacVim it crashes and the Terminal says: 
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.

I did a brew install macvim while in 1.9.3, but when I launch mvim from Terminal and run :ruby puts RUBY_VERSION I get back 1.8.7. I know Wincent recommends the system version of Ruby for installing Command-T and I've read you have to match up the Ruby version either way. I've managed to get it working for both when I had the system ruby, but can't get it for both on the RVM version with 1.9.3... 
Is it possible? Should I just forget about MacVim and stick with Vim in the Terminal?

Other things I thought I could do would be to have a disabled folder and just move the different Command-T installations in and out of it. Or maybe do an if for 'gui_running' and target the different installs. Any advice to set me straight would be great.

I've installed Tim Pope's rvm.vim and can set the Ruby version, but that doesn't seem to stop the crash in the MacVim when I call :CommandT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you installed the `macvim` package before you installed installed all the rest of that, and then installed the `vim` package afterwards.  That'd explain why it works in terminal mode.  These are two different packages, and they have their own build options.

Run:

```
vim --version
```

And compare the output to:

```
mvim --version
```

In particular, check out the last line (starts with `Linking:`).  You'll probably see `ruby-1.8` linked in for `mvim`, and `ruby-1.9.1` linked in for `vim` (note that 1.9.3 reports 1.9.1; it's the C API version, not the Ruby version).

If all this is true, fix it by doing:

```
brew uninstall macvim
brew install macvim
```

It should build against your 1.9.3 config.  Make sure `rvm current` reports 1.9.3 before you do that.

Comment: Optionally just stick with `vim` and save yourself the headache of slightly different versions, and get a head start on learning to love tmux.

Comment: Thanks Jim! looking at the --version for both really helped. I did try the brew uninstall and install a couple of times with my RVM Ruby set, before I posted here, so I thought I'd try a MacVim build the long way following the [MacVim Github build](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/Building) page. I'm running 10.8 and [found a patch](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/MacVim-and-Ruby-RVM-td3325517.html) for the --enable-rubyinterp \ that worked for setting my RVM ruby!

Comment: I also moved the mvim script from the MacVim build over to the /usr/local/bin directory so I could open MacVim from the Terminal. Everything seems good now when I look at the versions. I've put this in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/kaplan/5247004) for myself and anyone else that might have a similar issue

Comment: Glad you worked it out.  I bet brew was just falling back on your system Ruby.  It wouldn't make sense for brew to honor RVM.  I'll see if I can confirm that.